# #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `brands` (`id`, `brand_name`, `brand_status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
VALUES 
(1, 'Tata', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(2, 'Ford', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(3, 'Maruti', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(4, 'Honda', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(5, 'Hyundai', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(6, 'Volkswagen', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(7, 'Mahindra', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(8, 'Skoda', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(9, 'Renault', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(10, 'Fiat', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(11, 'Toyota', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(12, 'Nissan', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(13, 'Chevrolet', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
(14, 'Mitsubishi ', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '201[...]
```

Comment: Use _`_, try changing _id_ to _`id`_

Comment: And your database schema looks like what?

Answer (score 0):

if your `id` column is autoincrement , then you dont need to put `id` in insert query .

try this

```
INSERT INTO `brands` ( `brand_name`, `brand_status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
VALUES 
('Tata', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Ford', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Maruti', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Honda', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Hyundai', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Volkswagen', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Mahindra', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Skoda', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Renault', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Fiat', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Toyota', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Nissan', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Chevrolet', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
( 'Mitsubishi ', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '201[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use ID as primary key, and Does your table has 'id' as field?

```
 INSERT INTO `brands` (`brand_name`, `brand_status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
VALUES 
('Tata', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Ford', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Maruti', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Honda', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Hyundai', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Volkswagen', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Mahindra', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Skoda', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
('Renault', 0, '2013-12-05 13:30:00', '2013-12-05 13:30:00'), 
[...]
```